# Possible rep point bug with new profiles on stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

Seeing some weird inconsistencies today with my rep on my profile.

I have a self answered question: [AutoLayout multiline UILabel cutting off some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398042/autolayout-multiline-uilabel-cutting-off-some-text)

I got an upvote on the question (10 points) and an upvote on the answer (5 points) over an hour ago.

I opened my profile and it tells me that I have received 10 points since my last visit. I have received 15 points on the objective-c tag since my last visit. Which contradicts itself. Also I am 99% sure I didn't get those 5 points. I believe my rep should now be 5093 not 5088.

Not sure if theres a way to verify this on my profile. Is there? has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Look at the reputation audit page: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Oded Audit says my rep is 5093

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, something went wrong.

I queued your profile for a rep recalc. Should sort itself in a few minutes.

Comment: Showing up on stackoverflow now, thanks