# Did not get all reputation points from answer

Tags: support, reputation

Today I was sitting at a reputation of 351 on Stack Overflow. I then had my answer upvoted and accepted showing a + 25 in my reputation tab. My current reputation, however, is sitting at 361. As if the upvote counted in but not the "accepted answer" points.

Here is the question : [Windows Store dynamically add items into GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752546/windows-store-dynamically-add-items-into-gridview/29754001#29754001)

I then took a look at my profile and the graphic showing my rising reputation shows 376, as it should be, if I point to the very edge.

Any ideas why the graphic shows the proper reputation but the profile doesn't ?

EDIT :  stackoverflow.com/reputation shows 376 reputation

Comment: Maybe same problem as here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291216/3933332

Comment: perhaps try refreshing the web page? It helps by me

Comment: @Isaac no it really is a problem with the repuatation system. As I said the graph shows 1 score and the profile another. It has been like this for a few hours now.

Comment: yeah that is annoying

Comment: What do you see on http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: @NathanTuggy 376

Comment: I'm looking at your profile, and interestingly, it says that your reputation is 361 everywhere except in the reputation graph, which says (at the last data point) that your reputation is 376.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It seems the problem has been solved as your profile shows you have 376 rep now.

Comment: Yes that is weird it had a delay of around 7 hours

Comment: So, in addition to looking completely horrible, these new profiles mess up the rep ? Why don't you just go back to the old, well-tested profile...

Answer (score 6):

The cause of this bug remains unclear. However the points lacking were added around 6-7 hours after the question was accepted as answered.

I guess SO was experiencing some problems which have been solved, at least in my case.

Comment: Yes, that was odd. I confirmed that your rep did not add up just about 1-2 hours before you posted this.